Survey on the known and unknown results of uniform distribution of real sequences mod 1
Are there any existing survey on the known and unknown results uniform distribution of real sequences mod 1?
For example, polynomial sequences $\{p(n)\}$ (at least one coefficient other than the constant term irrational) are uniformly distributed mod 1, $\{\log n\}$ are not uniformly distributed, and whether $\{e^n\}$ is uniformly distributed is an open question.
I have seen people asking individual questions on this topic, but I am happy to see a summary of results or use this thread as a big list?

If a book counts as a survey, then there's the great "Uniform Distribution of Sequences" by Niederreiter and Kuipers. I also think there was a recent book that is HUGE.

@mathworker21 Thanks, what is that recent "huge" book?

I tried recalling ( I'm not just trying to tease ;) ), but I really don't remember and can't find it. I'll comment again if I remember.

@mathworker21: Probably the HUGE book is Distribution of Sequences: A Sampler by Oto Strauch and Štefan Porubský (18 January 2018 version; 690 pages). Curiously, I cited this recently (only a few days ago, I think) in a Mathematics SE comment, but I can't find it now in my recent comments. I suppose the question was deleted or my comment was deleted (but not by me).

@DaveLRenfro Yes, thank you!!

@mathworker21: Besides the .pdf file, I have a 2005 print copy of the book, and although it's much shorter (at xxii + 543 pages), flipping through the print copy is mind-boggling. According to my personal records, the 60 page bibliography of the 2005 edition has 1050 items. (Apparently I had nothing better to do one afternoon about 15 (?) years ago, since the bibliographic items are not numbered.)

There is also Sequences, Discrepancies and Applications (Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1651) 1997 Edition by Michael Drmota and Robert F. Tichy.
